# Symfony mail on Command class - get undefined method named "get"

Tags: symfony, email, cron, command

I try to send mail (swiftmail) via command of symfony.
Here is my code :

```
class CommandMail extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:send-daily-mail';

    protected function configure() {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Send automatic reminders mail everyday.')

            ->setHelp('This command allows you to send automatic reminder mail to Rhys, everyday...');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('test auto mail cron 12 24 TEST'))
                    ->setFrom('xxxxxx.xxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                    ->setTo('wwwww.wwwwwww@gmail.com')
                    ->setBody('test body');

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }
}
```

I have following error :

> In CommandMail.php line 54:
>                                                                                                                                                                                           Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
>   "AppBundle\Command\CommandMail".
>   Did you mean to call e.g. "getAliases", "getApplication",
>   "getDefaultName", "getDefinition", "getDescription", "getHelp",
>   "getHelper", "getHelperSet", "getName", "getNativeDefin     ition",
>   "getProcessedHelp", "getSynopsis" or "getUsages"?

I try many things (getContainer() ie and many others) but nothing is working.

Thanks for your help !

(Symfony 3, SMTP gmail)

Comment: I try to edit my message "Hi !!" doesn't working! Be understanding i'm new :)

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Symfony 3.4 normally (symfony 3 for sure)

Comment: I use swiftmailer with gmail smtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 4, inject the dependency by constructor:

```
private $swiftMailerService;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $swiftMailerService)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->swiftMailerService = $swiftMailerService;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('test auto mail cron 12 24 TEST'))
                ->setFrom('xxxxxx.xxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('wwwww.wwwwwww@gmail.com')
                ->setBody('test body');

    $this->swiftMailerService->send($message);
}
```

Comment: I get Command class "AppBundle\Command\CommandMail" is not correctly initialized. You probably forgot to call the parent constructor.

Comment: Add `parent::__construct();` to your constructor

Comment: Thanks both of you !!! With @AythaNzt code and Zak correction, it's working :)
Help a lot !